# Issues with JQuery and AWS S3 web hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created a website that uses 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js' for some javascript animations. I've hosted my website on AWS S3, but it seems like the animations aren't working. I believe it has something to do with CORS and allowing it use the jquery link, but I may be wrong. Any advice? Sorry if I'm not using the terms correctly, am just learning all of this. Please let me know if theres more information required to answer, I'll gladly update the question with it.

I have this statement at the end of my html code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/nav-main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hit the F12 key in your browser to open the Developer Tools and then reload the page. What does it say in the Console?

Comment: its not explicitly saying warning/issue, at the bottom of my html i have the code

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/nav-main.js"></script>

Comment: Press F12, go to the Network tab and see if the file is loaded correctly

Comment: it says 'failed to load response data' for jquery-latest.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your AWS S3 doesn't have access/permission to every link/Web from server, due to which jquery is not loaded. Download jquery file [Download jquery](https://jquery.com/download/) and try using this downloaded file in code.